# How to install boosting.m1 package in R?

Tags: r, boosting

How can I use the function adaboost.M1? I am testing the following codes in R. But I always have the error message: Error: could not find function "adaboost.M1". What packages do I miss? Thanks

```
library(rpart)
library(mlbench)
library(adabag)
data(iris)
names(iris)<-c("LS","AS","LP","AP","Especies")
iris.adaboost <- adaboost.M1(Especies~LS +AS +LP+ AP, data=iris, boos=TRUE, mfinal=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
iris.adaboost <- boosting(Species~., data=iris, boos=TRUE, mfinal=10)
```

Seems that in newer versions of **adabag** package you have to use method *boosting*.

Comment: It is actually boosting. Thanks!    
    
    iris.adaboost <- boosting(Species~., data=iris, boos=TRUE, mfinal=10)